# Polyglossia & IEETran

Tags: polyglossia

Using Polyglossia (Arabic Language) with IEEETran class (Journal Style) override the font and caption styles defined in IEEETran.

Any clue to overcome this issue?

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}


\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Amiri} % Replace 



% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls\\ for IEEE Journals}

\author{Michael~Shell,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}
        John~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Fellow,~OSA,}
        and~Jane~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Life~Fellow,~IEEE}% <-this % stops a space
}

% The paper headers
\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~14, No.~8, August~2015}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for IEEE Journals}

% make the title area
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{A Simple Example Table}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c||c}
\hline
\bfseries First & \bfseries Next\\
\hline\hline
1.0 & 2.0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Not many people here are acquainted with Arabic. Can you provide a minimal example of a document, from `\documentclass` up to `\end{document}` that shows the issue?

Comment: Please, add the code to your question.

Comment: Initial question edited to add the related code, removing the polyglossia chunks produce the correct style expected by IEEE.

Comment: The main problem is that `bidi` doesn't really know about `IEEEtran` and replaces the macros for `\caption` with an incompatible version. Do you plan to write some captions in Arabic?

Comment: I'm using arabic for tikz and for some content in tables but not for captions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't plan to use Arabic for the captions, you can restore the `\@makecaption` macro defined by `IEEEtran`, that gets modified by `bidi` in an incompatible way.

You also need to load a Times font that has small caps, otherwise the document will not follow the guidelines of IEEE that want Times.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

% save the IEEEtran definition
\makeatletter
\let\IEEEtran@makecaption\@makecaption
\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Amiri} % Replace 

% restore the definition and fix \tablename
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\let\@makecaption\IEEEtran@makecaption}
\appto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{TABLE}}
\makeatother


% correct bad hyphenation here
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}


\begin{document}

\title{Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls\\ for IEEE Journals}

\author{Michael~Shell,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}
        John~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Fellow,~OSA,}
        and~Jane~Doe,~\IEEEmembership{Life~Fellow,~IEEE}% <-this % stops a space
}

% The paper headers
\markboth{Journal of \LaTeX\ Class Files,~Vol.~14, No.~8, August~2015}%
{Shell \MakeLowercase{\textit{et al.}}: Bare Demo of IEEEtran.cls for IEEE Journals}

% make the title area
\maketitle


\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}
\end{IEEEkeywords}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{A Simple Example Table}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c||c}
\hline
\bfseries First & \bfseries Next\\
\hline\hline
1.0 & 2.0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's what I get if I remove the code from `% save the IEEEtran definition` up to the second `\makeatother` and compile with `pdflatex`:

[image]

If you don't have TeX Gyre Termes installed as a system font, you can still load it: change the `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}` declaration into

```
\setmainfont{texgyretermes}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*-regular,
  ItalicFont=*-italic,
  BoldFont=*-bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic,
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot egreg, IEEETran is not using Palatino font?

Comment: @user2133516 Not with `journal`, as far as I know.

Comment: I generated the PDF using your code, the font is different from the one generated using IEEETran without polyglossia.

Comment: @user2133516 They seem essentially the same to me. The small caps font differs slightly, because the `pdflatex` version is mechanically scaled.

Comment: They are different, this is the definition inside IEEETran.cls

\def\@IEEEstringptm{ptm} % Times Roman family
\def\@IEEEstringppl{ppl} % Palatino Roman family
\def\@IEEEstringphv{phv} % Helvetica Sans Serif family
\def\@IEEEstringpcr{pcr} % Courier typewriter family

Comment: @user2133516 You ***can't*** use `ptm` with XeLaTeX. That's why an OpenType font is necessary.

Comment: Using your code, \IEEEPARstart{C} yield and error "Font not loadable..." but removing \setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes} resolve this issue

Comment: Is there a way to save and restore font settings?

Comment: @user2133516 No. You may have to load TeX Gyre Termes differently, if you don't have it installed as a system font. I'll add the code.

Comment: Looking inside the generated PDF, I found different fonts, TexGyreTermes using your method, URWPalladioL-Roma if I don't use Polyglossia.